# Laravel getimagesize crashes with full URL

Tags: laravel

If I do this:

```
$image = '/storage/images/image.jpg';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
```

I get: `getimagesize(/storage/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` which makes sense because it doesn't have the full URL.

But if I do this:

```
$image = url('/').'/storage/images/image.jpg'; // Added url('/')
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
```

The page is stuck in the loading state forever...

Some additional info

- The public, storage and images folders all have the 755 permission
- The images itself have 644 and are displayed on the front-end
- I'm using the [Spatie Media Library](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction), and the image I'm trying to get the dimensions from is from a conversion. But as they're displayed perfectly fine on the front-end I wouldn't see why this would cause the script to crash the server
- This is on localhost

**Update**

As it looked like the server crashed I thought there would be no error logs, but there is:

```
getimagesize(http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): getimagesize(http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  at /Users/username/Documents/dev/test/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php:50)
```

Line 50 in PagesController is

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
```

and as indicated `$image = url('/').'/storage/images/image.jpg';`

If I enter the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/image.jpg` in the browser it displays the image.

**Update 2**

`file_get_contents($image)` gives the same behaviour, so it might have something to do with Laravel's routing or the fact that the script request is not the same as a browser request?

Update 3

In config/filesystems.php

```
'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and there is a symlink in the `public` folder created by `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Do you mean `getimagesize`, singular?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo. I'll update the question.

Comment: Try it without the slash before `/storage`

Comment: @digijay that would give `http://127.0.0.1:8000storage/images/image.jpg` which is incorrect. As indicated: if I copy and paste the URL from the error log into my browser it displays the image. So the URL is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to try this for the first approach, which is reading the image directly from the file system.

Comment: You are confusing local file with remote file read documentation on [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). Anyway, you can not access `storage` directory from your browser because web-server (if properly set) forbids it. You can access only files from `<root>/public` (if web-server properly configured).

Comment: @Kyslik from the docs there: It can reference a local file or (configuration permitting) a remote file using one of the supported streams. So it should be able to open a local file, and it seems to be something with the configuration.

Comment: You've got it wrong; anything that is under `<root>/public` can be accessed by anyone just like css / js files. If you want to use local file you need to reference **local** file. Which means you can not use http protocol to get it! You need to use `/var/www/application/storage...` or simply use Laravel filesystem if you set it properly - [local disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-local-driver).

Comment: The storage folder has a symlink into public. So there's both storage/app/public/images and that has a symlink to public/storage/images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to access `/storage/images/image.jpg`. Your real path is something like this: `/var/www/laravel.app/storage/app/public/images/image.jpg`.

You should use Storage facade and its `path()` method to retrieve full absolute path:

```
$image = Storage::path('public/images/image.jpg');
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
```

Or `storage_path()` helper:

```
$image = storage_path('app/public/images/image.jpg');
```